# What's the bottleneck when compiling a program?

Tags: eclipse

For example, doing an Eclipse build over a large project, I get neither 100% CPU load, nor 100% RAM load, nor 100% I/O. All of them are far below 30%. How is that? What is it doing and shouldn't there be a bottleneck be either in CPU, RAM, or I/O?

Comment: How many cores does your computer have? One way for a process to bottleneck below 100% utilization is if your reporting utility reports 100% utilization of one core of a four core machine as 25% CPU utilization.

Comment: Almost all builds are I/O bound. The disk system isn't going to show 100% utilization even if the build is spending a lot of time waiting on disk.